# Nested LINQ query returns null

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, nested

I'm trying to use the result of a first linq query in a where condition of a second one as follows:

```
var query = (from ds in Datacenter.datastatus
             where ds.visible == "y"
             select new
             {
                 ds.Priority,
                 ds.country.Country_Name,
                 ds.DSFromDate,
                 ds.DSToDate,
                 ds.country.ReceptionType_Id,
                 receptiontype = Datacenter.reception_type
                                           .Where(x => x.Id_reception_type == ds.country.ReceptionType_Id)
                                           .Select(x => x.Name)
                                           .FirstOrDefault()
             }).ToList();
```

We can see that I'm trying to **use the field ds.country.ReceptionType_Id to get the reception_type.Name property corresponding into the reception_type table**.

Except **this returns nothing**.

However, if I delete the following block from my query:

```
 receptiontype = Datacenter.reception_type.Where(x => x.Id_reception_type == ds.country.ReceptionType_Id).Select(x => x.Name).FirstOrDefault()
```

I get a resultset and **I can see that the values for the field ds.country.ReceptionType_Id exist**.

Then I've also tried to set a fixed value in the where condition as follows:

```
receptiontype = Datacenter.reception_type.Where(x => x.Id_reception_type == 1).Select(x => x.Name).FirstOrDefault()
```

And this time **I get a value for reception_type.name corresponding to reception_type.id = 1**

As well, I get a value for reception_type.name if I set x.Id_reception_type == 2 or 3 or..

So why does my second select work with a fixed integer value in the where condition **but not with the value ds.country.ReceptionType_Id** ?

Edit:

To make it clearer, I'm trying to do a triple join as:

- datastatus table contains a country_id
- country table contains a recepetion_type_id
- reception_type table contains the corresponding name I want to display

Comment: What is the result of `ds.country.ReceptionType_Id` in your first query?

Comment: it is the id of the table reception_type that is linked to a country

Comment: @Marc is the value of `ds.country.ReceptionType_Id` in the first query equal to 1?  Could it be a value that isn't in your `reception_type` table?

Comment: Are you only wanting records where the ID is the same in both tables? Looks like a basic join here, albeit implemented in a somewhat unorthodox manner.

Comment: I understood, but...ok in other words... look at the result of this: `(from ds in Datacenter.datastatus where ds.visible == "y" select new{ds.country.ReceptionType_Id}).ToList();`. Then take any id from this result and use it in that query where you user 1.

Comment: @juharr the values in the first query are multiple since it's a recordset of many rows, but all the ids are in the reception_type table as a checked it (you can see that I select the field ds.country.ReceptionType_Id in the first select to ensure that the value exist)

Comment: @Reniuz That's what I technically did in my second step when I remove the block with the second query, and I get a list of result with an existing value of ds.country.ReceptionType_Id on every row

Comment: And in second step you got ds.country.ReceptionType_Id with value 1?

Comment: @Reniuz No, in second step I have several records where some of them have receptionType_Id = 1 or 2 or... whatever. I just tried it to be sure that there were some correct ids in the field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to find a working solution for the exact same query using the following lambda syntax

```
var query = Datacenter.datastatus.Where(x => x.visible == "y")
                                 .Join(Datacenter.countries, 
                                       ds      => ds.Country_Id, 
                                       c       => c.Country_Id, 
                                       (ds, c) => new { ds, c })
                                 .Join(Datacenter.reception_type, 
                                       rcc      => rcc.c.ReceptionType_Id, 
                                       r        => r.Id_reception_type, 
                                       (rcc, r) => new { rcc, r })
                                 .Select(x => new 
                                                { 
                                                   x.rcc.ds.Priority,  
                                                   x.rcc.ds.country.Country_Name, 
                                                   x.rcc.ds.DSFromDate, 
                                                   x.rcc.ds.DSToDate,  
                                                   x.r.Name }
                                        ).ToList();
```